# Drop Column with foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_info` (
 `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 `initials` text NOT NULL,
 `surname` text NOT NULL,
 `home_lang` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
 KEY `home_lang` (`home_lang`),
 CONSTRAINT `personal_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`home_lang`) REFERENCES `language_list` (`ll_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `language_list` (
 `ll_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ll_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am trying to remove a column from a table with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `personal_info` DROP `home_lang`
```

But cannot do it since I recieve this error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\MyDB\#sql-112c_82' to '.\MyDB\personal_info' (errno: 150)
```

I have tried to first remove the index and then remove the column with this:

```
ALTER TABLE personal_info DROP INDEX home_lang
```

But then I get the following error:

```
#1553 - Cannot drop index 'home_lang': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

So I tried to drop the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE personal_info DROP FOREIGN KEY home_lang
```

But received this error:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\MyDB\personal_info' to '.\MyDB\#sql2-112c-8d' (errno: 152)
```

I have also tried to first set all the values to null:

```
update personal_info set home_lang = null
```

But then received this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`MyDB`.`personal_info`, CONSTRAINT `personal_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`home_lang`) REFERENCES `language_list` (`ll_id`))
```

And now I am stuck. I have tried a few things but just cannot get the column removed. I am not allowed to alter the DB in any way other than removing the column.

Comment: use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` to disable constraint

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `DROP FOREIGN KEY` syntax is using the wrong key name. It's trying to drop your "plain" index on the `home_lang` field. It's NOT the foreign key itself.

```
CONSTRAINT `personal_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`home_lang`) REFERENCES `language_list` (`ll_id`)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- THIS is the name of the foreign key
```

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE personal_info DROP FOREIGN KEY `personal_info_ibfk_1`
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this given below query to find the name of the foreign key.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE forms_main;
```

Then once u got the key, execute drop foreign key command

```
alter TABLE `forms_main`
drop FOREIGN key `forms_main_ibfk_1`;
```

Then execute the drop column command

```
ALTER TABLE `forms_main` DROP `company_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `foreign_key`;
ALTER TABLE `test`.`exam` 
DROP INDEX `id` ;

Comment: Suggestion for improvement of your comments: In addition to posting the solution, also add a few words on what this does, why it works and potentially why you recommend this solution over alternatives.

Comment: First you need to drop the foreign key using the query:                               
ALTER TABLE db_name.table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY foreign_key;          On creation of table an index for foreign key will be created, which should also be deleted using the query:                                                                                 
 ALTER TABLE test.exam DROP INDEX id ;

Comment: Hint: directly below your answer is an "edit" link that allows you to modify the answer itself ;)